# How do I write the code for dividing an even number with biggest equal odd numbers

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, numbers

I have a set of numbers to check. if the number is even, the program will check the biggest odd dividers of it which are equal. For example, if the number is 12, program will return an array like [3,3,3,3] or for 36, it will be [9,9,9,9] and let's say for 54, [27, 27] and 56, [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7] and so on. I am writing my code in ruby. I couldn't figure out how to write the correct algorithm. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
def fun(num)
  odd = num
  odd /= 2 while odd.even?
  [odd] * (num / odd)
end
```

How does this work?

This divides `num` by 2 until it is an odd number.

Comment: You need `[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]`, not just one `7`

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps:

Determining the number of times the number is divisible by two (assuming `in` is positive) - in **pseudocode**:

```
int divisors(int in):
    int divisor = 1
    for(; in % 2 == 0; divisor *= 2)
        in /= 2   //integer division!!!

    return divisor
```

`divisors` will return the largest power of two, by which `in` is evenly divisible. The idea is that any number `n` can be represented by it's prime-factorization, which is something like:

```
n = 2^a * 3^b * 5^c * ...
```

We only need to know `a`, as the rest of the factorization will necessarily be our largest odd divisor. Or in a bit more detail:

```
n = 2^a * 3^b * 5^c * ...
largest_odd_divisor = 3^b * 5^c * ...
largest_even_divisor = 2^a = divisors(n)
```

We can't find any larger odd divisor, since we only eliminated all even divisors from `n`, so we only got even divisors that we could add to `largest_odd_divisor`, but due to this the divisor would turn even.

The rest is trivial:
Get `a` (as shown above), create an array of size `2^a` and fill it up with `n / (2^a)`.

Comment: divisor will be 0 because `int divisor = 0`

Comment: @cuongptnk sry, I've just got an edit on the way. I'll correct that while I'm at it. Thanks

Comment: why don't you just return `in` ?

Comment: @cuongptnk `divisor(in)` is supposed to get the largest even divisor. I'll clarify that.

Comment: I see your point. I am thinking it in the reverse way, where you get the odd factor first.

Comment: @cuongptnk yup. Pretty much. I thought it would be easier to condense the whole thing that way, since all the arithmetic once the even divisor is found is even slightly more trivial than when you get the odd factor.

Comment: @akuhn correct. This is pseudo-code, since I just demonstrated an idea. Shouldn't be too hard to translate something as trivial as this into whatever language you want to use.

Comment: @akuhn whatever makes you happy. Though I'd say it's pretty obvious.

Comment: @akuhn static types, method-signature doesn't match the one used in ruby, neither does the loop. Anyone who's ever seen a single-line of ruby would notice that.